# AVAudioRecorder fails recordForDuration after MPMoviePlayerController play on iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, record, avaudiorecorder

I have weird problem on iOS5, on iOS6 it is working just fine :)

I'm able to record as much as I like using AVAudioRecorder, but if I do any playback using MPMoviePlayerController, recording fails. To be precise when I call recordForDuration (after playback) it is returning NO.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone experience something like this I found solution :)
Before recording you need to create AVAudioSession

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if (err)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
}
err = nil;
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
if (err)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
}
```

and it should work just fine :)